# SSH user1@ip_address: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh

I am trying to connect to a my SSH server (running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS) from my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS).

I have created a private and public key on my local machine and copied my public key to my SSH server's `authorized_keys` file.

I could log in with `ssh root@ip-address` and I have access (as root user), but when I tried to log in as another user with command `ssh name@ip-address`, it generated an error message:

```
name@ip_address: Permission denied (publickey)
```

What can I do so the `name@ip-address` could be accessed?

Comment: What OS/releases are you using on client/server?  root logins are not normal for Ubuntu and usually disabled.

Comment: @guiverc my server is using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, and Ubuntu 18.04.3 for my client

Comment: Alright, I made mistake. I didn't know that each user has their own `authorized_keys`. So I only add the public key on root's, after adding the key to this user, I can log in using it.

Comment: Yes, every user has their own authorized_keys. This allows a user called fred to log in *without* being granted root access, or indeed any other access.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `sshd_config` file.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
2. Change the following lines.

   ```
   PermitRootLogin prohibit-password to PermitRootLogin yes 
   PasswordAuthentication no to PasswordAuthentication yes
   ```
3. Restart ssh service.

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```

Comment: same error after  update

Answer (score 0):

**Here are a few of the first things I would check.**

*- Make sure the key in the authorized key file is marked as trusted.

- Make sure the account you are trying to use has ssh privileges.
- Make sure there are no typos in the username.*

[This page can tell you a lot about how to use ssh keys.](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/public-key-authentication)

[This page can tell you more about ssh keys.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)

**OTHER IDEAS**

*- If you want to check the account and make sure it has the proper
   privileges you can use command id  to see the user groups.

- Check your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to be sure you have the correct
  settings for ssh users.*

Hope this helps!